# What does this complicated return statement do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Browsing the [d3 source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js#L1970) today I saw the following line:

```
return delay <= elapsed ? start(elapsed) : d3.timer(start, delay, time), 1;
```

I've been doing daily javascript for years and have never seen that before. What the hey?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp These are used more in the weekly javascripts than the daily ones. May be why you haven't encountered them before.

Comment: your rep.. this question..

Comment: Yup, total brain fart. Been too busy eating all christmas day. I would delete this but loganfsmyth deserves the points.

Comment: @user93353 - according to http://w3fools.com, w3schools is not a good resource to use.  Here's an alternative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators

Comment: @user93353 Just wondering, what are daily and weekly javascripts?

Comment: @irrelephant - I don't know - the OP said he has been doing `daily javascripts` and had not ever encountered `<=`. So I assumed that `<=` is more used in `weekly javascripts`. Anyway, just a joke. Not so funny, coz I had to explain it.

Comment: Haha, indeed @user93353 - it comes up up on days 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 and so on. In all seriousness. I use underscore for all loop iteration so its honestly been a while since I've literally had to write that symbol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is just less-than or equal. Maybe the [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) combined with the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is what is throwing you off?

This is equivalent to this:

```
if (delay < elapsed) start(elapsed);
else if (delay === elapsed) start(elapsed);
else {
  d3.timer(start, delay, time);
}
return 1;
```

Comment: Wow. I posted this, got in the shower and immediately realized that **of course** I know what greater-than-or-equal-to means. So sorry. Have a picture of Frieda Khalo hanging out with Leon Trotsky with my apology: http://awesomepeoplehangingouttogether.tumblr.com/image/32307958593

Comment: So it always returns 1, because comma has higher precedence and groups the a?b:c expression ??

Comment: @GeorgeMauer It happens :) Not surprised. Yeah, the comma operator doesn't come up very often. I actually assumed it was added by the D3 packager, but it looks like it is in the original source too. I don't think it adds much benefit here though.

Answer (score 2):

Just means "less than or equal to".

Answer (score 1):

it means *if* the left hand operand is *less than* **or** *equal* to the right hand operand in nearly(*if not all*) languages

Answer (score 0):

<= means less-or-equal.

The complete line you posted means in plain english "if delay is less than elapsed, return start(elapsed), otherwise return the value of d3.timer.

Comment: The comma operator changes the return value.